# Difficult SQL statement... Four tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've put together a database, which I believe follows all the "right" ways of doing things, (No redundant data, etc.) as shown below:

[image]

I wish to display the data stored in the **Nominations** table, but by a certain *EventID*, and with the film *Title* and *Year*, and the award *Name*. I know basic joins, but this seems to be quite complicated -- because I'm a newb. Any help about the right way of approaching this problem, so I can face more complicated ones in the future, is much appreciated!

Comment: Show us the query you used. You seem to be almost there; why did you stop?!

Comment: The design seems good but there are several issues that can be improved. For example, it will be difficult to ensure that the `Awards.name` store the name of a `Nominees.name` that was actually nominated for the same `Nomination`.

Comment: @ypercube I'm not sure I follow. Could you clarify? Thanks. Note that `Awards.name` is the name of the award, yes?

Comment: Oh sorry, the `Award.Name` would be something like `'Best actor'`, not the name of the awarded person. I misunderstood.

Comment: @ypercube No problem, that's correct (`Awards.name` *would* likely contain `Best Actor`). Are there any other issues you can see with the structure?

Comment: You could post anothe question, specifically for the design. So you can have alternatives. For example, the `Nominated.NominatedID` is not needed. You can remove it and make the natural `(NomineeId, NominationId)` the Primary Key. The same can probably be done in the `Nominations` table. You'll get a long Primary Key in `Nominations` table and probably an even longer one in `Nominated`. In exchange, you'll have shorter joins (and proper normalization). You can look up on "Natural vs Surrogate keys" issue.

Comment: @ypercube Thanks, I've created the question so you can answer more fully: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143270/hows-my-data-structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Study "joins". These are an essential part of the use of SQL. Once you have a select statement that works, study "views" and create a new view using your select statement.

To get you started here is an untested, off the top of my head, example of a select statement using joins. Please also note that MySQL is not a tool I use often, so the syntax is probably not correct for MySQL.

```
SELECT A.Title, A.Year, C.Name, D.EventID
FROM FILMS A
JOIN NOMINATIONS B ON B.FilmID = A.FilmID
JOIN AWARDS C ON C.AwardID = B.AwardID
JOIN EVENTS D ON D.EventID = B.EventID
WHERE EVENTS.EventID = XX
```

This will work if all relationships exist. Study "outer join" to pull all the rows of a given table, say FILMS, and include matching row in the other tables.

An author named Joe Celko has written several books on complex SQL statements. You may find his work useful.

hth

Answer (score 2):

That is definitely the right way to structure this data, as it will allow you to aggregate your data quite succinctly. In actual fact, the query you're looking for is a simple series of joins:

```
SELECT
  n.*,
  f.Year,
  f.Title,
  a.Name
FROM `nominations` n
INNER JOIN `events` e ON n.EventID = e.EventID
INNER JOIN `films` f ON n.FilmID = f.FilmID
INNER JOIN `awards` a ON n.AwardID = a.AwardID
WHERE n.EventID = ?
```

In fact, you do not even need to join on the Events table, unless you want to retrieve data from the Ceremonies table.

Answer (score 2):

Work your query with the immediate qualifier first, then build out from that...  You want a specific "Event ID" type, go there.  Since the Events and Ceremonies are more of "Lookup" tables, you probably want all the qualifying nominations, so I'm actually going to start there.

```
select
      JustNominees.*,
      f.Title,
      f.Year as FilmYear,
      a.Name as AwardName
   from
      ( select 
              n.*,
              e.Name as EventName,
              c.Year as CeremonyYear
           from
              Nominations n
                 join Events e
                    on n.EventID = e.EventID
                    join Ceremonies c
                       on e.CeremonyID = c.CeremonyID
           where
              e.EventID = WhatEventID ) JustNominees
      join Films f
         on JustNominees.FilmID = f.FilmID
      join Awards a
         on JustNominees.AwardID = a.AwardID
```

Answer (score 1):

It is in fact a basic join, so you should know this already :-)

First select the right `nominations` and then join the rest with it:

```
SELECT nominations.nominationid,
       films.title,
       films.year,
       awards.name
FROM nominations
JOIN films
ON films.filmid = nominations.filmid
JOIN awards
ON awards.awardid = nominations.awardid
WHERE nominations.eventid = :event_id
```