# How's my data structure?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, data-structures

I've put together a simple database for storing information on awards and nominations. I've tried to remove as much data redundancy as possible. Here's how it's presently looking:

[image]

The reason for the Nominated table is that I realised that one nomination would have many nominees. For example, the award `Best Screenplay` could go to `Ken Levine and David Isaacs` or `Woody Allen` or `Joss Whedon, Andrew Stanton, Joel Cohen and Alec Sokolow`.

Note: `Award.name` is the name of the award, e.g. `Best Actor`.

Thanks for pointing out any possible improvements.

Comment: If the Award is the winner, why is it in a separate table to the nominees (after all, it must be one of the nominees)

Comment: @RowlandShaw `Award.name` is the name of the award, e.g. `Best Actor`.

Comment: Did you want to consider awards like "Lifetime achievement" which aren't associated with a film?

Comment: Just out of interest, what program did you use to design your diagram? It looks neat.

Comment: @Digbyswift Great question! Thankfully I don't believe I do. Phew!

Comment: @JamWaffles Being a complete newb I used Photoshop. Lol.

Comment: Maybe you should give it a different name, eg award_category, or just category?

Comment: Darn :-P I was hoping I had finally found a decent program for making database diagrams in!

Comment: @wildplasser Yeah, that might be a good idea, since it seems to have caused confusion a few times. So `Awards` becomes `Categories`. If you can think of a better name for `Nominated`/`Nominations` that would be good.

Comment: It happens often in data models that you have both a 'type' and an 'instance' of that type. Sometimes it helps to design a naming scheme for this.

Comment: @JamWaffles: In case you like my diagrams, they were made by MySQL Workbench.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt: Send me an email if you want the (workbench) file. Although you'll lose all the fun of creating them yourself :)

Comment: @ypercube Thanks very much! I can see me using Workbench quite a lot in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor notes

1. I prefer singular for table and column names so `Nominees` becomes `Nominee`, `Awards` becomes `Award`, etc.
2. Renaming the `Award` table as `AwardCategory` as @wildplasser suggested in comments.

---

Major notees

As @Olivier points out, the `m::n` relationships intermediate tables, like the `Nominated` one, will have a `UNIQUE` constraint on the compound `(NomineeId, NominationId)` . So, it's better to drop the auto generated (surrogate) key and make the compound key the `PRIMARY KEY`. This is the [natural key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) of the relation and there are several advantages of using it as the Primary Key. The [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) serves no purpose at all in this case except for having wider row and one more useless index. The two parts of the natural keys will be used for joining anyway.

The same thing applies for the `Nomination` table! The compound `(FilmId, AwardCategoryId, EventId)` will be a `UNIQUE` key, to ensure that no film gets 2 nominations for the same award category for the same event, so it's again better to drop the surrogate key and make this compound the primary key. Rethinking, we may have 2 nominations for the same AwardCategory for the same Film, say for two `'Best Supporting Actor'` so we add a `NominatioNo` in the Primary Key (this can be handy later if we want to restrict the nominations for a certain category or for all to say the constant 5).

Now, the (funny and interesting) thing is that the `Nominated` table has to be re-examined and have a compound `(NomineedId, FilmId, AwardCategoryId, EventId)` Primary Key - and just these 4 columns as attributes.

I'm not sure of what exactly the `Event` and `Ceremony` table are meant to store, but lets assume that the `Ceremony` table is meant to store information about different ceremonies (e.g. `'Oscar Awards'`, `'Strawberry Awards'`) and the `Event` table is to store information about a year's ceremony (e.g. `('Oscar', 2011), ('Oscar', 2012), ('Starwberry Awards', 2012)`). So i'll move the `Year` to the `Event` table and make the `(CeremonyId, EventYear)` the Priamry Key of Event. (I could very well be wrong this, you know your data better.).

So, the `Nomination.EventId` is replaced by `CeremonyId` and `EventYear` and the Primary Keys of both `Nomination` and `Nominated` get even longer! (that's one drawback of using natural keys as Primary Keys). Lets see what we've got so far:

[Database Design 1 http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/9592/oscarw.png](http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/9592/oscarw.png)

You can easily add a `NominationWinner` (as a table with `1:1` relationship to `Nomination`) to store which nomination won which category (a Unique constraint on `(CeremonyId, EventYear, AwardCategoryId)` would enforce that). The design would be like this:

[Database Design 1 http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/2108/oscar3x.png](http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/2108/oscar3x.png)

Having so complex primary keys may look clumsy but it helps when joining tables. Imagine you want to find all Winners for the 'Strawberry Awards' for the 50s and 60s and only for the 'Actresses' categories and also show for what film the award was for. You don't have to join all intermediate tables. Instead, you can retrive data using only the `NominationWinner`, `Nominee`, `Ceremony`, `Film` and `AwardCategory` tables (and using only the `Nominated` intermediate table):

```
SELECT ne.Name                AS Winner
     , wi.EventYear           AS Year
     , aw.AwardCategoryTitle  AS Category
     , fm.Title               AS FilmTitle
FROM
      NominationWinner AS wi
  JOIN 
      Ceremony AS ce
          ON ce.CeremonyId = wi.CeremonyId 
  JOIN
      AwardCategory AS aw
          ON aw.AwardCategoryId = wi.AwardCategoryId 
  JOIN
      Film AS fm
          ON fm.FilmId = wi.FilmId 
  JOIN
      Nominated nd
          ON  nd.CeremonyId    = wi.CeremonyId 
          AND nd.EventYear     = wi.EventYear 
          AND nd.AwardCategory = wi.AwardCategory 
          AND nd.NominationNo  = wi.NominationNo 
          AND nd.FilmId        = wi.FilmId  
  JOIN
      Nominee AS ne
          ON ne.NomineeId = nd.NomineeId 
WHERE 
      ce.CeremonyTitle = 'Strawberry Awards'
  AND wi.EventYear BETWEEN 1950 AND 1969
  AND aw.AwardCategoryTitle LIKE '%Actress%'
```

Comment: Wow. I'm going to have to go away and absorb this more fully. Thanks so much. One thing: "to ensure that no film gets 2 nominations for the same award category for the same event". This CAN happen. A film could have two different actors nominated for a supporting role, so the film has two different nominations in that category. (As happened at this year's Oscars with The Help.)

Comment: That's why I expanded the Primary Key, adding a `NominationNo` which you could set to be an integer (and also constrain it from 1 to 5 if  there are always 5 nominations per category). Unfortunately MySQL does not have constraints of the type: `CHECK (NominationNo BETWEEN 1 AND 5)`

Comment: Oops. Sorry. As I say, I need to go away and read through the whole thing and properly absorb it. Thanks so much for this, I look forward to thoroughly improving my data structure!

Comment: Huh. Someone downvoted your answer... for no good reason, as far as I can tell. Why do people do that, and then not bother to explain themselves? Annoying!

Comment: @Django: Anonymity is part of the site. I don't get annoyed much, not more than by anonymous upvotes :)

Comment: It annoys me because if they think someone is wrong in your answer, they should take the time to explain themselves. Such a thing is not needed with an upvote.

Comment: [Downvotes questions on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=downvotes)

Comment: I think you're missing my point: I don't care if it's anonymous or that they downvoted, it's that you've written a very thorough and detailed answer, and if they've spotted a flaw in it, they should share it!

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt No, I agree with you on that. I prefer an explanation, too, or an edit of my answer. If someone finds an error, he could correct it. If someone thinks the answer is wrong beyond repair, then I agree with downvoting.

Comment: And the link to meta was because I think this discussion belongs there, not here.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, well Meta has its own host of issues :) Never mind. Maybe whoever it was will post a comment eventually :)

Answer (score 2):

The `NOMINATED` table creates an m:n-relation between `NOMINEES` and `NOMINATIONS`. Drop its `NominatedID` column and use the two columns `NomineeID` and `NominationID` as primary key. This prevents the same person to be nominated twice for the same nomination.

```vb
 NOMINEES               NOMINATED
+---------------+      +---------------------+      NOMINATIONS
| PK  NomineeID |<----o| PK FK  NomineeID    |     +------------------+
+---------------+      | PK FK  NominationID |o--->| PK  NominationID |
|     Name      |      +---------------------+     +------------------+
+---------------+                                  | FK  FilmID       |
                                                   | FK  AwardID      |
                                                   | FK  EventID      |
                                                   +------------------+
```

Comment: Composite primary keys tend to be a little trickier to implement because you need to deal with two IDs instead of one. If you put a composite constraint on those two fields instead of making them the PK, you can still reference the row using its PK that represents the composite constraint. It's a little cleaner this way I think.

Comment: @JoePhilllips , I assume you're saying that I could add a Unique constraint on `NomineeID` and `NominationID`, while keeping `NominatedID`?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Yes, exactly

Comment: @JoePhilllips Unfortunately SQL is telling me that since there's no Index on `NominationID` that I can't add a FK relation to `Nominations.NomainationID`.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Add an index?

Comment: A FK must point to a PK or a unique index.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah, that did cross my mind :-/ It also complains if there's an Index on a column that's involved in a Unique.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Nice ASCII art! :)